# How to transimit video streaming from HoloLens (C#) to PC (python) by socket communication?

Tags: sockets, video-streaming, hololens

I can realize sending data from HoloLens (using Unity coding by C#) to PC (coding by C#) by socket communication. But how to sending video steaming in real-time (the video starts to be recorded when I open the application in HoloLens) from HoloLens to PC by my original socket frame. In my view, maybe I should add some sentences to recognize the HoloLens camera, record video and encode the video to data, then transmit the data by my previous socket. Is it right and how to realize it? 
By the way, I hope that the PC can receive the video by python so that I can process the video in the following steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send video steaming in real-time between HoloLens and PC client, WebRTC should can meets your needs. Please check out this [MixedReality-WebRTC](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC) project, it can help you to integrate peer-to-peer real-time audio and video communication into your application. It also implements local video capture you need and encapsulation it as a Unity3D component for rapid prototyping and integration.

You can read its official documentation via this link: [MixedReality-WebRTC 1.0.0 documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/index.html).

Moreover, this project can be used in desktop applications or even other non-mixed reality applications, which can save your development costs.